# Form selector failing $_POST['medalCount'] !== '' test

Tags: php, forms, http-post

In my post form, I have a selector for users to select the number of medals. In my `getSearchFields()` function, if the selector isn't empty (aka the selector is not on Select Medal Count), the function completes task 1. However, the selector is failing the `$_POST['medalCount']!== ''` test and is doing task 1. `$_POST['medalCount']` is type string. How do I fix this?

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="search">
<select name="medalCount">
    <option value=0 selected> Select Medal Count </option>
    <option value=1>1</option>
    <option value=2>2</option>
    <option value=3>3</option>
    <option value=4>4</option>
    <option value=5>5</option>
    <option value=6>6</option>
</select>
</form>
```

---

In `index.php`...

```
function getSearchFields(){
   if($_POST['medalCount']!== ''){
      //Task 1
      $search_fields['medalCount'] =$_POST['medalCount'];

   }
}
```

Comment: No **`<?php .... ?>`** tags... You're trying to mix JavaScript & PHP, that will never work.

Comment: How can your form ever submit an empty string value for `medalCount` (hint: it can't)?

Comment: @mickmackusa neither comment says that so I'm not sure why you bothered to add it :/

Comment: @Phil they insinuate RTM, but perhaps I gave the benefit of doubt about whether it was a typo.

Comment: @Darren I don't think OP was trying to mix JS and PHP, just some unfortunate formatting in their question

Comment: @Phil that does make sense now haha! The edit resolves it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
<option value=0 selected> Select Medal Count </option>
```

to this

```
<option value="" selected> Select Medal Count </option>
```

---

With all `<option>` elements having non-empty `value` attributes, you would never (normally) receive an empty string value in `$_POST['medalCount']` and `$_POST['medalCount']!== ''` would **always** be true.

Comment: I did your method, except I used single quotes `<option value='' selected> Select Medal Count </option>` and it worked

Comment: @15ongm the type of quotes generally don't matter (unless you're trying to validate your document against a DTD)

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong `$_POST['medalCount']!== ''`, You need to try `$_POST['medalCount']!= 0`. As your selectors empty value is `0`.